# Generating unique combinations of text

Tags: text, unique, combinations

I'm building a string of text from different parts. Group A + GROUP B + GROUP C + GROUP D.
The text is put together in this exact order. Each sentence is unique.

I randomly take one sentence from each group and put them together so the total combination of unique text would be A*B*C*D where A,B,C,D are the number of sentences in their respective group.

My problem is that how do i track that i don't generate duplicates in this way and when to know that i have used up all possible combinations?

Storing all possible combinations somewhere seems rather inefficient way to do this. So what options do i have?

Answer (score 0):

As random strings of text are pulled from each group, simply store the starting position of the sentence within the group along with the length into a container like a dictionary or perhaps HashSet.  This would act as the key to the container.  If the number of sentences in each group is small enough, you might be able to pack the data into a single integer or long value, otherwise define a structure or class for it.  The code should look in the container to see if the random combination generated has already been used.  If it has been used, then loop until a unique one has been found.  If the total number of combinations is small enough such that the user might go through them all, then pre-calculate the total-count and check to see if the container reaches that count, in which case some sort of exit processing should be performed.